# .NET MVC 4.5 - Section not defined

Tags: razor

I'm rendering a Razor template and would like to define sections, to which I'm able to add content throughout all included pages (namely, javascripts).
However, all sections so far have come up as empty. If I set them to required: true, I get the error that the section has not been defined. To test this, I added the following code to my main template file:

```
@section foo {
    <p>Hello</p>    
}
@RenderSection("foo", true)
```

These lines are right on top of each other. The rendering of the template fails with the message `Section not defined: "foo".`

Given that the section is obviously defined, did I maybe miss something in the Project configuration or Controller to enable support for sections? All other @commands (like `@RenderBody()`)inside the template seem to work fine, so some support for the Razor commands is clearly present.

Comment: You will find your answer in this blog post [ASP.NET MVC 3: Layouts and Sections with Razor](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/30/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor.aspx) from Scott Guthrie

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like you're defining your section and trying to render it from your shared layout.  As I understand it, you need to call RenderSection in your shared layout and then define the section it your views that use that shared layout.

This link from Scott Gu is a pretty good reference for sections:

[MVC 3 Layouts & Sections](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/30/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor.aspx)

Comment: Actually I tried that first - defining the section's content in sidebar.html, then including sidebar.html from main.html and rendering the section in main.html. Same result - the above code was only for clarification.

Comment: Could you please provide a full listing of what your view and shared layout markup look like?

Comment: I found the mistake - you can't define sections in templates that are rendered by RenderPage(). Apparently sections can really only be defined from the actual View templates that are being passed from the Controller.

Comment: Does this mean that if you render a section in your _layout file, that every other view file HAS to have that section defined in it?