# cshtml view "Section not defined: "featured2"

Tags: c#, razor

I'm wondering why for one of my views I get the error "Section not defined: "featured2"". The path to the layout is correct, and I define the featured2 section in the view.

View

```
@using System.Data;
@using System.Data.SqlClient;
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Attempted Unauthorized Access";
Layout = "../Shared/Layout2.cshtml";
string whoareyoupeople = User.Identity.Name.ToString();
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
string myerrorstring = "User " + whoareyoupeople + " attempted unauthorized access on " + date + ".";

    string fileName = "C:\\BillingExport\\SECURITY\\seclog.txt";
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write)){
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
    {
        sw.WriteLine(myerrorstring);
    }
}
}
@section featured2 {
<body>
    <head></head>
<center><h2 style="color:red">Access Denied for user @User.Identity.Name. You are not authorized to view this application.</h2></center>
    </body>
}
```

Layout2

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Layout2";
}

<link runat="server" rel="icon" href="../Content/images/eifavicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
@RenderSection("featured2")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
                <script>
                                         browsername = navigator.appName;
                                         if (browsername.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1) {
                                             browsername = "MSIE";
                                             document.write("<p id='indent2'>You're viewing this page using Internet Explorer. Please use a supported browser (<a href='https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/'>Chrome</a>, <a href='https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/'>Firefox</a>)</p>");
                                         }

</script>
```

Comment: Are you able to successfully build your solution? Try closing and reopening visual studio, that shouldn't be happening.

Comment: Yes, it builds. I tried restarting Visual Studio 2012, did not solve the issue. When I try to visit the view while the debugger is running, it just right to my Layout2.cshtml and highlights featured2 as not being defined.

Comment: How is your view being rendered? Is it in a RenderPage() declaration?

Answer (score 0):

C Bauer's question is a valid one, are you rendering this view from a RenderPage()?

> You can't define sections in templates that are rendered by
>   RenderPage(). Sections can really only be defined from the actual View
>   templates that are being passed from the Controller.

[Similar Stack overflow question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18191311/net-mvc-4-5-section-not-defined)